# How to Scroll the Left Quadrant

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

How can I make Selenium run scroll only in the left quadrant?

when I use the command below it is executed in the zoom of the map and that is not my intention, because I want to scrape the links of the companies that are in the left column

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 200)")
```

[image]

Comment: Please share a link to the page you working on

Comment: I would try moving the mouse to the window then scrolling, or seeing if any of the scroll function have a parameter to determine where the scroll should happen

Comment: https://www.google.com.br/maps/search/lanchonete,/@-27.0027727,-48.6293259,15z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the scrollable `div` element and then you can apply JavaScript as following:

```py
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='main']//div[contains(@aria-label,'lanchonet')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", element)
```

The code above works for me.
The entire code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url = "https://www.google.com.br/maps/search/lanchonete,/@-27.0027727,-48.6293259,15z"
driver.get(url)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='main']//div[contains(@aria-label,'lanchonet')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", element)
```

you can, of course, scroll for other lengths, not only for the entire height.